# Random template embedding?

Tags: ee2, templates, embeds, random

I know you can easily load a random entry from a channel, but I wanted to know if the functionality exists in EE to randomly embed and load a template from a group?

Thanks in advance for any guidance on this.

Comment: can you explain why you want to do this??

Comment: I want part of a homepage to randomly rotate promos on load. I know other ways to accomplish this, but it made me think of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick thought come to my mind is to create templates with the same name and change the prefix number for e.g: test_1,test_2,test_3......,test_100

then use this plugin to generate the random number:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/random-between

```
{embed='test_{exp:ga_randombetween start="0" stop="100"}'}
```

Regard's.

Comment: Good suggestion -- I'm assuming this also means it's can't be done native in EE.